# Limit at infinity -

Tags: calculus, limits

I don't even know where to start on this one. It's obvious that it's infinity, but how to prove it? $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n+2n^n+n!}{(n+1)^4+\sin n+(3n)!}$$

Comment: Why is it obvious?

Comment: Because n to nth power is the fastest growing element in that expression and its in numerator, I guess...

Comment: Having the mind of a Computer Scientist, I cant help but read this as $n^n / n!$

Comment: @DerFlatulator You're right we read this as $2n^n/(3n)!$ since $3^n=o(n^n)$ and $n!=o(n^n)$and $\sin n=o((3n)!)$ etc

Comment: And $n^n$ grows faster than $n!$. Thus as $n\to\infty$, $2n/(3n)!$ approaches $\infty$

Comment: n^n does grow faster than n! but only just. Their ratio is about exp(n). (3n)! grows faster than both. So I think the answer is zero. All the other terms are irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: start rewriting it as
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{n^n
\left(
\dfrac{3^n}{n^n}+2+\dfrac{n!}{n^n}
\right)
}
{(3n)!
\left(
\dfrac{(n+1)^4)}{(3n)!}+\dfrac{\sin n}{(3n)!}+1
\right)
}
$$